# cascade = "all-delete-orphan"

Tags: hibernate

what are the best coding practices for cascade all-delete-orphan in hibernate

Answer (score 2):

It's a configuration option. Use it when appropriate.

Comment: thank for ur reply i had used cascade="all-delete-orphan" in *.hbm.xml file i am getting the following exception can you pls tell how to resolve this                                             RegisteredSyn E   WTRN0074E: Exception caught from before_completion synchronization operation: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at at org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup$TransactionManagerAdapter$TransactionAdapter.setRollbackOnly(WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup.java:211)
 at org.hibernate.transaction.CacheSynchronization.setRollbackOnly

Comment: @sreelatha: put that as a new question, since it has nothing to do with your original question.

Answer (score 2):

```
  class Foo{
    Set<Bar> bars;}
class Bar{
    Foo parent;
    String localIdentifier;
}

hbm.xml files 

<class name="Foo">
    ...
    <set name="bars" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" inverse="true">
        <key>...</key>
        <one-to-many class="Bar"/>
    </set>
</class>


<class name="Bar">
    ...
    <property name="localIdentifier" column="local_identifier"/>
    <many-to-one name="parent" column="parent_id" />
</class>
```

Comment: i had done same as you said but lazy attribute as true ...can you pls tell whether i need to do any modifications in dao's?

Comment: can you please elaborate your problem !!....